# Should I single handedly close a question as dupe refering to a question I answered?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

Say I can single handedly close a question as a dupe (gold badge in the relevant tag), and the dupe I am referring to has an only answer, provided by me.

It feels a bit fishy to close it single handedly in this case, but - it is a dupe.

I currently only commented that I think it is a dupe, is it the right course of action?

What should I do?

Comment: Removed "example" because I don't want it to be the issue of the question - is it really a dupe or not. Have a look at the question's history if you're interested - but that's really not the issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go ahead and close it if it's a duplicate, that's what you got the hammer for.

Yes, it's answered by you, but it's actually expected that you are more conversant with your own posts, and will thus prefer them. As a side-effect, you'll get to look at it again and make sure it's as good as possible.
If you are actually wrong, perhaps because the OP forgot to mention something important or whatever, the community can correct it (Though you should be prepared to do so yourself, iff a coherent argument is made).

Comment: I never though about the fact that dupehammer might even be intended for you to duplicate point to your own stuff (since you are sufficiently an "expert" for the tag).  That actually makes sense since you can say "Hey I've answered this very question before."

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Even if it's wasn't _intended_ for that, it's certainly clearly understood that if you're a high-rep user with a lot of activity in a certain tag, a significant number of the good answers are yours, and it would be silly to expect you not to refer to that significant number of good answers.

Comment: The biggest problem with "prepared to do so yourself" is that the times I've discovered I was wrong, it's usually because there's an even better dup out there (usually answered by Martijn Pieters), and I can't reopen and reduphammer… but that's a whole other topic…

Answer (score 5):

If you think it's a duplicate, isn't the alternative simply copying & pasting your answer?

In this regard, closing it as a duplicate is *less* fishy.

Comment: Well, there are other alternatives—ignoring the question, trying to find a less-good-but-still-good-enough dup that isn't yours, sockpuppeting, deleting your original good answer… But I agree that none of them are as good as closing as a dup.

Comment: Well, of all of those, closing as dup is probably the best option, and copying & pasting your old answer to the new question is the second best option.  Another possibly alternative if you really must, know another gold-badger and ask them to dup-close it.

Comment: I think closing as dup is by far the best option (which is what your answer implies); pestering another gold-badger or wasting a mod's time with a flag are probably better than all the others, including copy-paste, but still not exactly good.